# Validate / modify store bindings before update

Tags: input, event-handling, svelte, store

I'm trying to validate and modify a store value before the store is updated. Running when a number input is changed. But what is happening now is that when the number input is changed to the wrong value (-1 or less), the store is first updated with the wrong value and then its changed to the correct value. Which results in the store updating twice.

Store.js

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const availableTrainingMaterials = writable({
    T1: 0
});
```

Materials.js:

```
<script>
    import { availableTrainingMaterials } from '$stores';

    $: if ( $availableTrainingMaterials.T1 < 0 ) {
          $availableTrainingMaterials.T1 = 0;
       }
</script>

<div class="available-materials">
    <h2>I have these materials:</h2>
    <div>
        T1: <input bind:value={$availableTrainingMaterials.T1} type="number" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom store that wraps the `set` function, which is used to update the store, e.g.

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

const { set, subscribe } = writable({
    T1: 0
});
export const availableTrainingMaterials = {
    subscribe,
    set: value => {
        if (value.T1 < 0)
            value.T1 = 0;

        set(value);
    },
};
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/05ceeda7c6924396b5eaf0598b471c6f?version=3.52.0)